# Why does jQuery Mobile select menu placeholder not work properly in iOS web app version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am building an iOS web app with jQuery mobile and the select box properly turns the first option with an no value into a header in the select pop up that is not selectable however when I add to homescreen as an iOS web app the select pop up menu then has the unselectable header as well as the option with the name as a selectable option...

Here is my markup:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>GWG</h1>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="content" id="homeContent">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
            <select id="selManufacturer" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Manufacturer</option>
            </select>
            <select id="selModel" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Model</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="thefooter">
        <h4>Created by: Thomas Dexter</h4>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And my javascript:

```
//Manufacturer select box
$('#selManufacturer').empty();
$('#selManufacturer').append('<option>Manufacturer</option>');
for (var i=0; i<json.phones.manufacturers.length; i++) {
    $('#selManufacturer').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + json.phones.manufacturers[i].name + '</option>');
}
$('#selManufacturer').selectmenu();
$('#selManufacturer').selectmenu('refresh');

//Model select box
$('#selModel').empty();
$('#selModel').append('<option>Model</option>');
for (var i=0; i<json.phones.models.length; i++) {
    $('#selModel').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + json.phones.models[i].model + '</option>');
}
$('#selModel').selectmenu();
$('#selModel').selectmenu('refresh');
```

And if you want to add the app to your iOS homescreen to see the problem goto

http://tsdexter.com/gwg

and click 'add to homescreen'

(the only models are currently iPhones, I'm aware that the filtering based on manufacturers is not currently implemented)

UPDATE: It looks like it may have been a caching problem with a version before I added the placeholder properly. Will do further testing and post back.

If that's the problem - does anyone know how to clear the cache of iOS homescreen web apps? I deleted the app, closed all pages in safari, force closed safari then opened it and re added the web app and it was still not working. Seems the only thing that fixed it was waiting 20-30 mins and then refreshing...

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Not really. I determined it was a cache problem but never figured out exactly how to properly clear the cache of the iOS homescreen web apps. The project was discontinued so I didn't end up looking much further into it. Let me know if you find something

Comment: will do and post it here, if I find out something